# Customize Spark DataFrame with extension points

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I m trying to extend `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset -> def show(numRows: Int)` method with spark extension points.

I know I can extend parser as

Define custom parser by coping spark source code

```
val extension = create { extensions =>
      extensions.injectParser((_, _) => MyCatalystSqlParser)
}
```

Set it to spark session

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf)
         .withExtensions(extension)
         .master(masterUrl).getOrCreate()
```

Is there slimier way to extend Dataset `show()/select()/join()` methods.

Comment: I'm wondering what would be the use-cases for that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Or this is just out of curiosity?

Comment: Extend performance.of these method by customizing few places inside these methods, specially join